# Adding multiple vertical lines for each frame in animated plot using plotly

Tags: python, animation, plotly

**Summary**: I am looking to add multiple vertical lines based on date values within each (animation) frame in an animated horizontal bar plot in **plotly**. What I want is to compare the existing date and new date for each task within each location (Please refer below dataset), and further point out the unique "new" date values in the plot. So I slide across each location frame and display the grouped bar plots across tasks comparing dates (existing vs new). Much easier to understand if you please refer below snippet (totally reproducible) I put together along with the charts below.

Next:

1. I want to include a dotted line for each of the unique new dates at the end of the horizontal bars for each selection of location (animated frame) through slider (possibly using `add_shape` in a loop of frames?). The *expected* chart output is shown below (first one) with red dotted lines passing through the edges of each date bars of unique height. Any other thoughts on showing unique "new" dates welcome!
2. Is there any way to dynamically control for data labels (dates) such that the dates are visible within the chart? Currently my chart output doesn't consistently show up the labels fully within chart area. For example, please refer to the second chart below for selected location slider "S1". The constraint is I don't want to leave out lot of spaces extending the x-axis ranges arbitrarily to a far future date.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks much in advance!

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from plotly import graph_objects as go

#Read in sample data
inputDF = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SauvikDe/Demo/main/Test_Dummy.csv')
    
#Format to datetime
inputDF['Date_Existing'] = pd.to_datetime(inputDF['Date_Existing'])
inputDF['Date_New'] = pd.to_datetime(inputDF['Date_New'])

#Sort required columns to plot better
inputDF.sort_values(by=['Location', 'Date_New', 'Date_Existing'], inplace=True)
```

The data looks like this (first few records):

```
Location,Task,TaskTimeMins,Date_Existing,Date_New
S1,E10,60,7/14/2022,7/14/2022
S1,E12,75,7/21/2022,7/14/2022
S1,SM0,40,7/21/2022,7/28/2022
S1,E16,60,7/28/2022,7/28/2022
S1,SM1,120,7/28/2022,7/28/2022
S1,E18,120,8/4/2022,7/28/2022
```

And, my working code to plot dynamic chart using **plotly** is as below:

```
# Create frames for each location
frames = []
for s in inputDF['Location'].unique():
    t = inputDF.loc[inputDF['Location'] == s]

    frames.append(
        go.Frame(
            name=str(s),
            data=[
                go.Bar(x=t['Date_Existing'],
                       y=t['Task']+":["+ t['TaskTimeMins'].astype(str)+" Minutes]",
                       xaxis="x", 
                       name="Existing Date", 
                       offsetgroup=1, 
                       orientation='h',
                       text=t['Date_Existing'].dt.strftime("%d-%m-%y"),
                       textposition='outside',
                       marker_color='#f4af36'#'#f9cb9c'#'#9fc5e8'#'#fff2cc'
                      ),
                go.Bar(x=t['Date_New'], 
                       y=t['Task']+":["+ t['TaskTimeMins'].astype(str)+" Minutes]",
                       xaxis="x2", 
                       name='New Date', 
                       offsetgroup=2, 
                       orientation='h',
                       text=t['Date_New'].dt.strftime("%d-%m-%y"),
                       textposition='outside',
                       marker_color='#38761d'#'#6aa84f'#'#08ce00'
                      ),
            ],
            layout={"xaxis":{"range":[t['Date_Existing'].min() - pd.offsets.DateOffset(1),
                                      t['Date_Existing'].max() + pd.offsets.DateOffset(30)],
                             #"dtick":"M3",
                             #"tickformat":"%d-%b-%y",
                             #"ticklabelmode":"period",
                            },
                    "xaxis2":{"range":[t['Date_Existing'].min() - pd.offsets.DateOffset(1),
                                       t['Date_Existing'].max() + pd.offsets.DateOffset(30)],
                              #"dtick":"M3",
                              #"tickformat":"%d-%b-%y",
                              #"ticklabelmode":"period",
                             },
                   },
        )
    )

# Create the figure, also set axis layout
fig = go.Figure(
    data=frames[0].data,
    frames=frames,
    layout={
        "xaxis": {
            "showticklabels":True,
         },
        "xaxis2": {
            "showticklabels":True,
            "overlaying": "x",
            "side": "top",
        },
    },
)

# Update dynamic chart title for each frame
for k in range(len(fig.frames)):
    fig.frames[k]['layout'].update(title_text=
                f"<b>Location: {fig.frames[k].name}</b> >> Date comparison:Existing vs New",
                                  )


# Finally create the slider
fig.update_layout(
    barmode="group",
    updatemenus=[{"buttons": [{"args": [None, {"frame": {"duration": 2000, "redraw": True}}],
                               "label": "&#9654;",
                               "method": "animate",},],
                  "type": "buttons",}],
    sliders=[{"steps": [{"args": [[f.name],{"frame": {"duration": 0, "redraw": True},
                                            "mode": "immediate",},],
                         "label": f.name,
                         "method": "animate",}
                        for f in frames ],
             }],
    legend=dict(orientation="h",
                yanchor="bottom",
                y=-0.5,
                xanchor="right",
                x=0.7,
               ),
    font_size=12,
    font_color="blue",
    title_font_family="Calibri",
    title_font_color="purple",
    title_x=0.5,
    width=950,
    height=600,
)

# Position play button
fig['layout']['updatemenus'][0]['pad']=dict(r=10, t=395)

# Position slider
fig['layout']['sliders'][0]['pad']=dict(r=10, t=50,)

# Print chart
fig.show()
```

[image: Expected output with red dotted line added]

[image: Issue with dates getting overflown outside chart]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have edited my question providing as much details as possible to help answer it. Hope this works.